# jQuery scrollTo resize issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

Update: the script and scrollTo animation now work fine. I've uploaded the correct solution.

I'm working on a Bootstrap 3 based website and I'm having some scrollTo issues, this is the code for a navbar (links from the nav lead to three different sections within the page):

HTML:

```
<header id="page-header" class="container">
    <h1> NMS website </h1>
    <img src="assets/images/group-logo.png" alt="group logo">
    <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top' role='navigation'>
        <h2> Page navigation </h2>
        <div class='navbar-header'>
            <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse'>
                <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='collapse'>
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#brands">Brands</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact-scroll">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header> <!-- end of page header -->
```

JavaScript (Modernizr library included for media query support, also I've used offset because the navbar is fixed and is overlapping the content area after scrollTo animation by default):

```
$(function () {

// making our anchors "scrollable"

var x;

$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top-x
    }, 700);
    return false;
        }
    }
  });   

function responsive () {


if(Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 768px)')) {    
        x = 85;
    }

if(Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 767px)')) {    
        x = 180;
    }   

}

responsive();

$(window).resize(function () {
    responsive();
});
```

});

and as you can see, I'm using this piece of code - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ for making scrollTo effects. Scrolling doesn't work that great, the problem occurs when I resize the browser window. When I go from desktop to mobile (without refreshing the page) the scrolling animation won't work that well (it doesn't recognize the "mobile" script first, so when I click on a link in the menu it will first run the offset from non-mobile script, and then it will run the offset for mobile script, which makes a non-pretty animation). But if I resize the window to mobile and then refresh the page (just like opening the page from a mobile device for the first time), my scrolling works great. Same thing goes for non-mobile window sizes as well. I hope I made this question clear? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are repeating a whole complex function twice, with the only difference being one single value, `85` vs `180`(?) – now that’s not very clever to begin with. Make that _one_ function, that takes that value from a variable. And then write code appropriate to change the value of that variable according to current screen dimensions when those change.

Comment: … or have the value calculated/read dynamically inside the function, depending on where those values actually come from (which you didn’t specify in your question, you just put those _magic numbers_ in there).

Comment: CBroe, you are a God! Thanks! I've just made a variable which stores those two values 85 and 180 differently depending on the media query, and defined a function only once. Works like a charm.

Comment: Good, put what you’ve come up with into a self-answer then :-)

Comment: Just did it. Thanks again : )